# 400 Bad Request while inserting mail to Gmail iff mail contains large attachment(more than 5 mb)

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-api, build.gradle

> com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
>
> at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
>       at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
>       at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
>       at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
>       at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1065)
>       at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
>       at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
>       at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
>       at org.gradle.GradleTest.insertMessage(GradleTest.java:132)
>       at org.gradle.GradleTest.main(GradleTest.java:173)

This exception occurs only when we try to insert mail having large attachments(more than 5mb).

If attachment is smaller then mail is getting inserted properly.

To insert mail I tried :

```
File file = new File(email);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            long fileSize = file.length();
            byte[] buf = new byte[(int)fileSize];
            int readNum = fis.read(buf);

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            baos.write(buf);

            String encodedEmail = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(baos.toByteArray());

            Message message = new Message();
            message.setRaw(encodedEmail);
            message = service.users().messages().insert(userId, message).execute();
```

Please suggest solution to insert mails having attachment more than 5mb.

Answer (score 1):

The [Gmail API documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads) says:

> You can make upload requests in any of the following ways. Specify the method you are using with the uploadType request parameter.
>
> Simple upload: uploadType=media. For quick transfer of smaller files,
> for example, 5 MB or less.
>
> Multipart upload: uploadType=multipart. For
> quick transfer of smaller files and metadata; transfers the file along
> with metadata that describes it, all in a single request.
>
> Resumable
> upload: uploadType=resumable. For reliable transfer, especially
> important with larger files. With this method, you use a session
> initiating request, which optionally can include metadata. This is a
> good strategy to use for most applications, since it also works for
> smaller files at the cost of one additional HTTP request per upload.

Since you want to send data > 5 MB, use the multipart or resumable option. Example for multipart: (taken from the docs as well):

```
public static MimeMessage createEmailWithAttachment(String to,
                                                        String from,
                                                        String subject,
                                                        String bodyText,
                                                        File file) throws MessagingException, IOException {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        MimeMessage email = new MimeMessage(session);

        email.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        email.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO,
                new InternetAddress(to));
        email.setSubject(subject);

        MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        mimeBodyPart.setContent(bodyText, "text/plain");

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(mimeBodyPart);

        mimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);

        mimeBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        mimeBodyPart.setFileName(file.getName());

        multipart.addBodyPart(mimeBodyPart);
        email.setContent(multipart);

        return email;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide link for resumable upload option?

Comment: @Renuka: I can't find an example in the docs either, so I'd need to write ony myself. Maybe I find time during the weekend